# Jackson single argument constructor with single argument fails with ParameterNameModule

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson

I am using Jackson 2.8.5 with ParameterNamesModule for Java 8 (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8).

My problem is very specific for one use case, when I want to de-serialize a class with a single constructor using a single argument. Here is a test to reproduces the behavior:

```
public class JacksonTest {

    @Test
    public void TestReadValue() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)
                .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES));

        ImmutableIdentity identity = objectMapper.readValue("{\"id\":\"ABCDEF\"}", ImmutableIdentity.class);

        assertEquals("ABCDEF", identity.id);
    }

    private static final class ImmutableIdentity {

        private final String id;

        public ImmutableIdentity(final String id) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(id, "The id must not be null.");

            this.id = id;
        }
    }

}
```

The test fails with the reason:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of JacksonTest$ImmutableIdentity, problem: The id must not be
>   null.  at [Source: {"id":"ABCDEF"}; line: 1, column: 15]

The funny thing is that if I add another argument to the constructor, the test passes OK.

```
public class JacksonTest {

    @Test
    public void TestReadValue() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)
                .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES));

        ImmutableIdentity identity = objectMapper.readValue("{\"id\":\"ABCDEF\"}", ImmutableIdentity.class);

        assertEquals("ABCDEF", identity.id);
    }

    private static final class ImmutableIdentity {

        private final String id;

        public ImmutableIdentity(final String id, **final String unused**) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(id, "The id must not be null.");

            this.id = id;
        }
    }

}
```

I really don't like the idea to use a useless argument in the constructor here to make it less ambiguous, because it has no value in my business objects, especially they are for instance ProjectId, or some abstract Id that defines my entities and I need to construct them manually as well. So I would like to find a configuration of Jackson to support this but I could not.

I also crossposted here for the maintainers: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you by any chance compiling `JacksonTest` with `-parameters` option? If so, this is expected behavior.
Single argument constructors were historically used as delegating creators.
I've had discussions about this matter with @staxman even when we created the module. The issue popped up a number of times by various users, see [this issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-parameter-names/issues/21) for details.
Looking to the future, this will hopefully be changed in 3.0, see [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jackson-dev/2xkHrvL2HTI) for details.

Update: regarding 3.0 change, see [this issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1498). If you want this behavior to change please add +1 or comment. Right now it isn't clear if either approach is better as there are users that need the old behavior (see the issue for more details).

Comment: Ok so you mean single argument constructors are ambiguous because of legacy behavior ? I understand now, thank you for the answer and links to those discussions.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for a fix/workaround: "if class Person has a single argument constructor, its argument needs to be annotated with @JsonProperty("propertyName")" Source: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/blob/master/parameter-names/README.md

Comment: It's enough to annotate the constructor with `@JsonCreator`. You shouldn't need `@JsonProperty`

Comment: What about the situation where the class can't be modified (for example, I'm deserializing a library class)? Still looking for a solution to that case when I can't add the `@JsonCreator` annotation.

Comment: Probably the way to go would be to register a custom deserializer.
You can also try https://github.com/infobip/infobip-jackson-extension#SingleArgumentPropertyCreatorAnnotationlessSupport