# Define default constructor for record

Tags: java, java-14, java-record

I have a record and want to add default constructor to it.

```
public record Record(int recordId) {
   public Record {

   }
}
```

But it created constructor with `int` param.

```
public final class Record extends java.lang.Record {
    private final int recordId;
    public Record(int);
    //other method
}
```

How can we add a default constructor to a record?

Comment: what you defined is a compact constructor which gets its declaration derived from the record header. There is a 1-1 match in name, type and variable arity between a record component and the corresponding formal parameter in the compact constructor, same applies for the canonical constructor. A record can only have a canonical constructor. If declared the compact constructor is the canonical constructor

Answer (score 71, accepted):

To split hairs, you cannot ever define a default constructor, because a default constructor is generated by the compiler when there are no constructors defined, thus any defined constructor is by definition not a default one.

If you want a record to have a no-arg constructor, [records do allow adding extra constructors or factory methods](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/records-come-to-java#anchor_8), as long as the "canonical constructor" that takes all of the record fields as arguments is called.

```
public record Record(int recordId) {
   public Record() {
      this(0); 
   }
}
```

Comment: A constructor taking no argument is called `default`. The compiler creates a default constructor by default. you can propose another implementation of the default constructor. Then, the compiler does not use the by default one anymore.

Answer (score 33):

#### Explicit constructor

In your case, you can explicitly specify a no-argument constructor with the delegation to the canonical constructor with a default value if you want to and this can be done as -

```
public Record(){
    this(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}
```

In short, any non-canonical constructor should delegate to one, and that should hold true for the data-carrying nature of these representations.

#### Compact Constructor

On the other hand, note that the representation you had used in your code.

```
public Record {}
```

is termed as a "compact constructor" which represents a constructor accepting all arguments and that can also be used for validating the data provided as attributes of the record.  A compact constructor is an alternate way of declaring the canonical constructor.