# MapStruct - No converter found for return value of type

Tags: java, mapstruct, java-14, java-record

I want to use records from java 14 with entity (from java persistence). I try to map my user to userDto and my debbuger show that all is correct mapped. But unfortunettly I got the error when I want to print my userDto:

`Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class xxx.UserMicroservice.dto.UserDto]`

What I'm doing wrong?

```
public interface UserMapper {
    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    UserDto mapToUserDto(User user);
}
```

```
public class UserMapperImpl implements UserMapper {

    @Override
    public UserDto mapToUserDto(User user) {
        if(user == null) {
            return null;
        }
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto(user.getName(), user.getEmail(), user.getImageUrl());
        return userDto;
    }

}
```

```
public record UserDto(
        String name,
        String email,
        String imageUrl) {}
```

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/user/me")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public UserDto getCurrentUser(@CurrentUser UserPrincipal userPrincipal) {
        UserDto userDto = UserMapper.INSTANCE.mapToUserDto(userRepository.findById(userPrincipal.getId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "id", userPrincipal.getId())));
        return userDto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to deserialize when using new Record classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140857/unable-to-deserialize-when-using-new-record-classes). Deserialisation of records is not solved straightforward I guess!

Comment: I added default no args constructor to record but it still not working (the same error)

Comment: It's not just the default constructor, I meant to focus on the deserialization part, getters/setters their naming convention etc as well.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62486959/3553087