# How to insert an immutable record using spring-data-jdbc

Tags: java, spring, immutability, spring-data-jdbc, java-14

Entity is

```java
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

import java.util.UUID;

@Table
public record Picture(
        @Id UUID id,
        UUID galleryId,
        String metadata
) { }
```

Note that the ID is a UUID assigned client-side so I'm not interested in any sort of IDs assigned automagically by the database.

The repository:

```java
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PictureRepository extends CrudRepository<Picture, String>, WithInsert<Picture> {
}
```

```java
public interface WithInsert<T> {
    T insert(T t);
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate;

public class WithInsertImpl<T> implements WithInsert<T> {

    private final JdbcAggregateTemplate template;

    public WithInsertImpl(JdbcAggregateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @Override
    public T insert(T t) {
        return template.insert(t);
    }
}
```

when I invoke `repository.insert(picture)` I end up with the following error:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot set immutable property [...package redacted away...].Picture.id!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.setProperty(BeanWrapper.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.AggregateChange.setIdAndCascadingProperties(AggregateChange.java:177) ~[spring-data-relational-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.AggregateChange.populateIdsIfNecessary(AggregateChange.java:144) ~[spring-data-relational-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.6.RELEASE]
```

Question is: is there a way I can use immutable Entity with spring-data-jdbc ?

Rant: immutability is good, UUIDs are good, auto-increment is bad. I think it's quite an assumption that I want auto-increment necessarily and I'd like to be able to shut it off in case I don't want it.

EDIT:
I'm using spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.2.6.RELEASE which comes with spring-data-jdbc:1.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: Looks like a deserialization failure, which is [about known with records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140857/unable-to-deserialize-when-using-new-record-classes) not following JavaBean naming conventions.

Comment: Which version of Spring Data JDBC are you using? Can you try the latest 2.0.0 RC? That issue should be fixed there.

Comment: Jens, thanks for the comment. I can't test it right now but I'll try to in the next days

Comment: I just noticed that you updated the question. If you update a question in reaction to a request of another user let them know by mentioning them in a comment.

Comment: Sorry for (wrongly) removing the java-14 tag – You may want to consider using/adding the tag: java-record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was found and fixed during the work for version 2.0.0. of Spring Data JDBC.

If you still see this behaviour or need a backport to 1.1.x please create an issue on https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC