# Jackson cannot construct instance with one parameter constructor

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, lombok

I am using Spring Boot to create a web application. One of the endpoints expect a json object having one property, i.e. `studentId`. I am using DTO like my other functions to capture the payload.

```java
@PostMapping("/courses/{id}/students")
public SuccessResponse<Void> addEnrolls(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody StudentIdPayload payload) throws HandledException {
    courseService.addEnrolls(id, payload.getStudentId());
    return success(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentIdPayload {
    private Long studentId;
}
```

But when I tried to post the endpoint with json body `{"studentId":1}`, I got the following error :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.bimoadityar.univms.dto.input.StudentIdPayload` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

While it works if I post using just the value `1`.

How can I get it to work with the object payload?

Interestingly, when I add another property to the `StudentIdPayload`, such as `String placeholder`, it works as intended, although this solution feels hacky.

Comment: Found a relevant question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243608/jackson-single-argument-constructor-with-single-argument-fails-with-parameternam, with a corresponding issue https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1498

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, deserialization requires no-args constructor, so add `@NoArgsConstructor`:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class StudentIdPayload {
    private Long studentId;
}
```

see also:

- [Annotations: using custom constructor](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind#annotations-using-custom-constructor)

Comment: Considering Data annotation has RequiredArgsConstructor in it, and I don't have any private final properties, I'm sure a  no-args constructor already exists if it's required.

Comment: When `@AllArgsConstructor` is added explicitly, `@RequiredArgsConstructor` in `@Data` is not effect.

Comment: This actually works. I was mistaken, I'm sorry. But I'm really surprised this solves my problem considering I use the same annotation for all the other endpoints and it works just fine. Oh well. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Confirmed this resolved the same issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Considering https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1498, it seems that this is the intended behavior.

For my particular case, I am satisfied with adding the `@JsonCreator` to my constructor.

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator))
public class StudentIdPayload {
    private Long studentId;
}
```